# Display unique count despite decimal value in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to display a count of 1 even if the value is a decimal, or 0.5

Data

```
id  date    var value
aa  Q1 2022 h_aa    0
aa  Q1 2022 hx      1
aa  Q1 2022 hbb     0.5
bb  Q2 2022 see     0
cc  Q3 2022 ok      0.5
cc  Q3 2022 uu      2
dd  Q4 2022 ut      4
```

Desired

```
id  date    var count
aa  Q1 2022 hx  1
aa  Q1 2022 hbb 1
cc  Q3 2022 ok  1
cc  Q3 2022 uu  2
cc  Q3 2022 uu  2
dd  Q4 2022 ut  4
dd  Q4 2022 ut  4
dd  Q4 2022 ut  4
dd  Q4 2022 ut  4
```

Logic: for the case of cc, there are 2 'uu' values, so I would like this to be displayed twice and reflecting that there are 2 counts

If the value is 0, the record does not even appear

If the value is a decimal, it should still be counted as 1 (as in the case of 0.5)

Doing

```
newdf = (pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,df.value.astype(int),axis=0))).rename(columns= 
{0:'id',1:'date',2:'var',3:'count'})
```

However, this removes the 0.5 values and does not include them in the count. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `(df.value + 0.5).astype(int)`?   Or `np.ceil(df.value)`?

Comment: ok I see - I should run this code before the script I provided?

Comment: No, INSTEAD of `df.value.astype(int)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there, The suggestion of @TimRoberts was right:

```
mask = df['value'] > 0

newdf = df[mask].assign(value=np.ceil(df.loc[mask, 'value']).astype(int))
newdf = newdf.reindex(newdf.index.repeat(newdf['value']))
```

```
>>> newdf
   id     date  var  value
1  aa  Q1 2022   hx      1
2  aa  Q1 2022  hbb      1
4  cc  Q3 2022   ok      1
5  cc  Q3 2022   uu      2
5  cc  Q3 2022   uu      2
6  dd  Q4 2022   ut      4
6  dd  Q4 2022   ut      4
6  dd  Q4 2022   ut      4
6  dd  Q4 2022   ut      4
```